# Replace pattern values in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

i am having string "Test uid=1 Test2 uid=2 Test3 uid=3"

i wrote regex to get all uid.

That gives me list of uid {1,2,3}

for this values i have some diff values 
{1 = 2015, 2=2016, 3=3014}

I tried to use Regex.replace(str, regexPattern, "")

As it replace all the regex matching item by single value.

Now i want to replace this old values by new value.

Code

```
string str = "Test uid=1 Test2 uid=2 Test3 uid=3"
var uiList = regex.Matches(str);
```

I am thinking about MatchCollection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the version of [Regex.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace.aspx) accepting [MatchEvaluator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator.aspx) - [Regex.Replace Method (String, String, MatchEvaluator)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy.aspx)

Sample method (without checking of input data):

```
string input = "Test uid=1 Test2 uid=2 Test3 uid=3";
var replacements = new Dictionary<string,string> {
    { "1", "2015" },
    { "2", "2016" },
    { "3", "3014" }
};
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<=uid=)\d+", m => replacements[m.Value]);
```